# How do I join three tables and get a boolean value based on foreign keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple database containing salesmen and districts. A district can only have one responsible salesman (ResponsibleSalesmanId column in Districts table), but can have multiple secondary salesmen (shown in the SecondaryDistrictSalesmen table).

Here's my database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Salesmen]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Districts]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [ResponsibleSalesmanId] INT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Districts_Salesmen] FOREIGN KEY ([ResponsibleSalesmanId]) REFERENCES [Salesmen]([Id])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SecondaryDistrictSalesmen]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [DistrictId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [SalesmanId] INT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SecondaryDistrictSalesmen_Districts] FOREIGN KEY ([DistrictId]) REFERENCES [Districts]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SecondaryDistrictSalesmen_Salesmen] FOREIGN KEY ([SalesmanId]) REFERENCES [Salesmen]([Id]) 
)
```

What I would like to output from this database is a table containing all salesmen from the database and their relation to a specific District (specified by a WHERE [District].[Id]=x).

I was thinking about adding two additional columns to the output result: IsResponsible and IsSecondary. If the given salesman in each column is responsible for the input District, IsResponsbile should contain 1 (and 0 if not) and likewise for the IsSecondary column.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Can a sales person have more than one role?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Please tag SQL questions always with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . seems like `union all`:

```
select id as DistrictId, ResponsibleSalespersonId as SalespersonId, 1 as IsResponsbile, 0 as IsSecondary
from Districts
 where id = @X
union all
select DistrictId, SalespersonId, 0, 1
from SecondaryDistrictSalesperson
where DistrictId = @X;
```

EDIT:

I originally misunderstood the question.  I thought you only wanted the sales people from a particular district.  Assuming that a sales person only appears once in the two tables, then:

```
select s.*,
       (case when d.ResponsibleSalespersonId is not null then 1 else 0 end) as IsResponsble,
       (case when sds.SalespersonId is not null then 1 else 0 end) as IsSecondary,
from salesperson s left join
     districts d
     on d.ResponsibleSalespersonId = s.id and
        d.districtid = @distictid left join
     SecondaryDistrictSalesperson sds
     on sds.SalespersonnId = s.id and
       sds.districtid = @districtid;
```

Comment: How do I include the rest of the Salesmen that have 0 in both IsResponsible and IsSecondary?

Answer (score 1):

Cross join all salesmen with all districts. Thus you already see the whole result set and who is primary salesman. In order to see whether a salesman is secondary, either outer join the third table or use an exists clause.

```
select
  s.id, s.firstname, s.lastname,
  d.id, d.name,
  case when s.salesmanid = d.responsiblesalesmanid then 1 else 0 end as is_primary,
  case when sds.salesmanid is not null then 1 else 0 end as is_secondary
from salesmen s
cross join districts d
left join secondarydistrictsalesmen sds on sds.salesmanid = s.salesmanid
                                        and sds.districtid = d.districtid
order by s.id, d.id;
```